# Ionic 4 FileOpener plugin_not_installed

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to open a PDF using `FileOpener`. I followed this tutorial https://ionicacademy.com/create-pdf-files-ionic-pdfmake/ which is for Ionic 3 so I had to adjust a few things. I have it working in the browser and on the iOS simulator, but when I test on my device through the Ionic Viewer app, I get an error saying `plugin_not_installed` when I click the download button and `downloadPdf()` gets called.

I have installed the cordova plugins via:
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2` and 
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    File,
    FileOpener
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  letterObj = {
    to: 'Ronnie',
    from: 'Shana',
    text: 'my message'
  }

  pdfObj = null;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private plt: Platform, private file: File, private fileOpener: FileOpener, private alertController: AlertController) { }

  createPdf() {
    var docDefinition = {
      content: [
        { text: 'REMINDER', style: 'header' },
        { text: new Date().toTimeString(), alignment: 'right' },

        { text: 'From', style: 'subheader' },
        { text: this.letterObj.from },

        { text: 'To', style: 'subheader' },
        this.letterObj.to,

        { text: this.letterObj.text, style: 'story', margin: [0, 20, 0, 20] },

        {
          ul: [
            'Bacon',
            'Rips',
            'BBQ',
          ]
        }
      ],
      styles: {
        header: {
          fontSize: 18,
          bold: true,
        },
        subheader: {
          fontSize: 14,
          bold: true,
          margin: [0, 15, 0, 0]
        },
        story: {
          italic: true,
          alignment: 'center',
          width: '50%',
        }
      }
    }
    this.pdfObj = pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition);
  }

  downloadPdf() {
    if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
      this.pdfObj.getBuffer((buffer) => {
        var blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        // Save the PDF to the data Directory of our App
        this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'myletter.pdf', blob, { replace: true }).then(fileEntry => {
          // Open the PDf with the correct OS tools
          this.fileOpener.open(this.file.dataDirectory + 'myletter.pdf', 'application/pdf')
            .then(() => this.presentAlert('opened'))
            .catch(error => this.presentAlert(error)); // Error thrown here.
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // an error
          this.presentAlert(error);
        })
      });
    } else {
      // On a browser simply use download!
      this.pdfObj.download();
    }
  }

  async presentAlert(message) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      subHeader: 'Subtitle',
      message: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();
  }

}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Ionic Viewer App does not support many plugins... Search for a list of supported plugins and check if FileOpener is in there.

Comment: @robbannn that didn't even cross my mind. Makes sense why it works in the simulator then. I thought I was going crazy. Looks like its here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp/#native-cordova-plugin-support

Comment: @Ronnie I am also using same blog. but is working fine in android and ios.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari is it working through Ionic DevApp though?

Comment: @Ronnie what you mean by Ionic DevApp?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari The issue is I am accessing the app via Ionic DevApp and the FileOpener library doesn't seem to be supported which is why it is not working for me. I believe my code is actually fine since it works on the simulator.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari I also just realized I linked the wrong tutorial, but I have updated it

Answer (score 2):

The import path as shown in the doc [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener) is apparently wrong.
I used to get "Invalid provider for ngModule", so searching in the plugin source files I found a different import path, which apparently works.

I could import the plugin using

```
import { FileOpener } from "@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx";
```

both in my app.module.ts and in my page.

Comment: the docs are indeed wrong. Working with Ionic 4 beta, all packages were imported with `/ngx` after which is why I have that in my OP. Your answer doesn't really answer this question. It was answered in the comments and it was just that Ionic DevApp only supports X number of modules https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp/#native-cordova-plugin-support